# Laravel 5 application moved from local machine to hosting server causing errors

Tags: php, web, laravel-5, ftp, hosting

I developed an application in laravel 5.0 in local machine using xampp and it's working fine. After i uploaded the project to hosting server using ftp now i am getting following errors one below the other.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you don't have right permission on `project/storage/framework/sessions` folder, so give the permission to `0777` i.e `read write execute` and after that run the following command:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

through `terminal` or `putty` on server and every thing will be fine.

Comment: Where to run? You mean in server ?

Comment: i manually deleted files in following folders `project/storage/framework/cache` , `project/storage/framework/sessions` and `project/storage/framework/views` but still getting same error.

Comment: run the command and see what happens: `php artisan config:cache`